# logrotate configuration on linux to rotate syslog-ng log files correctly

Tags: logging, logrotate, syslog-ng, rotation

I am having some trouble trying to configure log rotation for some syslog-ng local log files I'm trying to keep.

for some reason, the size is not respected and logs are filling my filesystem quickly.

I want to keep something like 3 files of 100Mbs or 3 files of 500Mbs for log files.

my current log rotation configuration is the following :

```
[root@xm1p1034vmo logs]# cat /etc/logrotate.d/syslog-ng
#
/app/syslog-ng/logs/syslog-ng.log {
missingok
notifempty
rotate 3
compress
maxsize 50M
daily
create 0600 root root
postrotate
    /bin/kill -HUP `cat /app/syslog-ng/var/syslog-ng.pid 2> /dev/null` 2> /dev/null || true
endscript
}
#
/app/syslog-ng/logs/outgoing*log {
missingok
notifempty
rotate 3
compress
daily
maxsize 100M
create 0600 root root
postrotate
    /bin/kill -HUP `cat /app/syslog-ng/var/syslog-ng.pid 2> /dev/null` 2> /dev/null || true
endscript
}
#
/app/syslog-ng/logs/incoming*log {
missingok
notifempty
rotate 3
compress
daily
maxsize 500M
create 0600 root root
postrotate
    /bin/kill -HUP `cat /app/syslog-ng/var/syslog-ng.pid 2> /dev/null` 2> /dev/null || true
endscript
}
```

the crontab is every 3 hours (could put it more often if required) :

```
# Logrotate
00 03,06,09,12,15,18,21,23 * * * /usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf >/dev/null 2>&1
```

but as you can see, the log files are much bigger and grow quickly :

```
[root@xm1p1034vmo logs]# ls -al
total 8065908
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root       4096 May  2 09:07 .
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root       4096 Dec 20 16:08 ..
-rw-------  1 root root    5330231 May  2 17:12 cid.log
-rw-------  1 root root 4284556769 May  2 17:12 incoming_all.log
-rw-------  1 root root   18081021 May  2 09:07 incoming_all.log-20170502.gz
-rw-------  1 root root   22753799 May  2 17:12 outgoing_esx.log
-rw-------  1 root root      93372 May  2 09:07 outgoing_esx.log-20170502.gz
-rw-------  1 root root    1718167 May  2 17:12 outgoing_fireeye.log
-rw-------  1 root root       8633 May  2 09:07 outgoing_fireeye.log-20170502.gz
-rw-------  1 root root     362817 May  2 17:09 outgoing_iseries.log
-rw-------  1 root root       2706 May  2 09:07 outgoing_iseries.log-20170502.gz
-rw-------  1 root root      15838 May  2 17:10 outgoing_mssql.log
-rw-------  1 root root        345 May  2 09:07 outgoing_mssql.log-20170502.gz
-rw-------  1 root root      57358 May  2 17:11 outgoing_nas.log
-rw-------  1 root root        722 May  2 09:07 outgoing_nas.log-20170502.gz
-rw-------  1 root root      13932 May  2 16:42 outgoing_network.log
-rw-------  1 root root        197 May  2 09:07 outgoing_network.log-20170502.gz
-rw-------  1 root root   11991510 May  2 17:12 outgoing_oracle.log
-rw-------  1 root root      46817 May  2 09:07 outgoing_oracle.log-20170502.gz
-rw-------  1 root root        664 May  2 12:15 outgoing_printers.log
-rw-------  1 root root        174 May  2 09:07 outgoing_printers.log-20170502.gz
-rw-------  1 root root     407191 May  2 17:12 outgoing_san.log
-rw-------  1 root root       1968 May  2 09:07 outgoing_san.log-20170502.gz
-rw-------  1 root root 3896682829 May  2 17:12 outgoing_unix.log
-rw-------  1 root root   16055682 May  2 09:07 outgoing_unix.log-20170502.gz
-rw-------  1 root root    1179031 May  2 17:12 outgoing_win.log
-rw-------  1 root root       2845 May  2 09:07 outgoing_win.log-20170502.gz
-rw-------  1 root root       4003 May  2 16:47 syslog-ng.log
-rw-------  1 root root        386 May  2 09:07 syslog-ng.log-20170502.gz
[root@xm1p1034vmo logs]#
```

what did I do wrong in the logrotate/crontab config please ?
I want to keep 3 logs of 100Mb for every outgoing* log file, and 3 logs of 500Mb for every outgoing* log file

thanks
regards,

Answer (score -2):

Change maxsize to size and that should do it for you